# Minimum technology required to discover relativity?

Tags: civilization, scientific-development, relativity

As the title states, **what’s the least-powerful technology a civilization needs before they are capable of developing and verifying an accurate theory of special & general relativity?**

For details, let’s say that the civ’s technological development roughly corresponds to that of Earth at any given point in time and that they have ready access to demonstrations of relativity (like precessions of elliptical rocky-planet orbits near their home star, visible gas giants with several moons that can be observed to lens spacetime with a good enough telescope, and maybe even a nearby black hole that can be seen with decent telescopes and that observably alters the flow of time for nearby objects). Also suppose that their home world is sufficiently similar to Earth that they can launch stuff into space about as easily as we can.

Comment: can you make clear the difference with this other question? https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/255899/30492

Comment: (to my understanding,) that question asks whether or not a given civ is capable of developing a theory relativity at all; I’m asking what the minimum tech requirement is to develop *and* effectively verify relativity. Similar questions no doubt but I think they are different enough to merit different posts.

Answer (score 4):

General Relativity does not have a monopoly on predicting obital precessions and the bending of light around massive objects. Classical mechanics *also* predicts these effects. What General Relativity does is predict *different values* for these effects than what classical mechanics predicts.

<sup>And the differences are observable only in, well, *special* situations. For example, a *lot* of artificial satellites are launched into what are called [heliosynchronous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun-synchronous_orbit), or Sun-synchronous, orbits, which are orbits around Earth which precess so that the orbit precesses exactly 360° in one year, thus having the satellite always remain in the same position relative to the Sun from the point of view of an observer on the ground. Classical mechanics is good enough for calculating such orbits, there is no need for fancy General Relativity.)</sup>

Einsteinian Special Relativity was developed in order to reconcile classical mechanics and classical electromagnetism with the requirement that all the laws of physics should be the same in all inertial frames of reference. *This* was the real, painful tension which the new theory resolved. Albert Einstein's 1905 paper in which he first described Special Relativity had the title "Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Körper", On the Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies.

Quite obviously, in order to develop Special Relativity a civilization needs (1) advanced calculus, (2) classical mechanics, and (3) a mathematical formulation of electromagnetism. They need advanced calculus because that's the essential tool which is needed for classical mechanics and classical electromagnetism. They need both classical mechanics and classical electromagnetism because if they have only one of them there is nothing to reconcile...

For classical mechanics they need good mechanical technology, including decently good clocks. For a mathematical theory of electromagnetism they need relatively good electrotechnics, that is, electric generators, and motors, and transformers, and instruments of measurement for electromagnetic quantities, because otherwise they wouldn't even have the raw experimental data to build on.

In real history, Special Relativity was formulated about 50 years after the invention of the first useful electric generators, or about 40 years from the formulation of Maxwell's mathematical theory of electromagnetism, or about 25 years after the introduction of the first viable electric locomotive by [Werner von Siemens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werner_von_Siemens) (yes, that [Siemens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siemens)).

General Relativity is an extension of Special Relativity, which does not need any supplementary knowledge. In real history, General Relativity was developed within ten years from the formulation of Special Relativity.

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's see. Special Relativity was developed in part as an attempt to explain the failure of the Michelson-Morley Experiment to detect the luminiferous ether, i.e. the result that the measured speed of light was independent of the direction it was measured in relative to the Earth's motion. The MM Experiment was conducted using a Michelson interferometer. To build an interferometer, you need a steady light source and a half-silvered mirror as a beam splitter, or two prisms glued together. The experiment used an Argand burner, a bright oil lamp, as its source of white light. https://history.aip.org/exhibits/gap/PDF/michelson.pdf

So really, it doesn't seem like a society would need more technology than oil lamps and mirrors to be capable of taking the first steps toward relativity. However, you'd also need to have the necessary mathematical foundations laid to do the calculations. I remember Carl Sagan saying that Einstein was partly inspired by watching trains passing each other and wondering about their relative frames of reference, but I suppose it's possible that a comparable genius from a pre-rail society could have been inspired by a different analogy.

Answer (score 0):

You compare this question in some ways to earth.

When Einstein discovered relativity, and special relativity, including time dilation, etc., the technology did not exist for most or all of the rest of the scientists in the entire world at that time.

Many years ago, when studying quantum mechanics, I was supplied with some books on the life of Einstein. In them I read that his discovery was influenced by the some French experiments. Much thought later, Einstein noticed that their data was verified many times by many scientists, and thought about it. He said that if all supplied data is true, and if all conclusions are wrong, then there must be another conclusion (however seemingly illogical and seemingly unscientific) which was correct. He thought through the possible variations and found that the only one that was not proven to be unchangeable was time. Therefore, he applied the answer that time changed and the problem was solved.

Relativity could have been discovered (in your game) at a technology level where people have use of good quality mirror, a shutter that is fast enough with the ability to measure (which both could be by use of a large diameter spinning wheel), and a scientist that is willing to take chances with thought. I would expect maybe equal to about 1,000 years ago (in Europe) the technology level would have been enough for this. Maybe in Mesopotamia a few thousand years before that. Maybe about 4,000 years ago if the technology the Chinese had then (maybe during the Ming dynasty) was used. Time dilation was observed by Einstein (reportedly) by thought and consideration of conditions without an overriding need to follow the crowd or to be scientifically politically correct or to be in total acceptance of someone else's dictates of how to think. He was ridiculed almost world-wide by other scientists at the time but not now. Simple to advanced in a single leap of thought.

Comment: *"The French attempting to measure the distance between two hill tops":* Citation needed. Please edit the answer to provide a reputable source for this extraordinary claim. I would be *extremely* surprised if the effect described in this answer is real. (Because no matter whether you shine a light from A to B or from B to A, you can only measure the time it takes light to go both ways...) (And they had absolutely no way of measuring such small intervals of time in the early 1900s.)

Comment: So, I suppose that you are saying that everyone that was before you showed up on this planet was less capable than you. You said it, "they had absolutely no way of measuring such small intervals". OK, so be extremely surprised. Surprise!

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest way to approach a question like this is to look at what the earliest times that each of the discoveries leading up to relativity could have been discovered are in our world, assuming each was adopted as soon as it was proposed.  So, I think the first things that need to be established before we can start working toward gravity in general, much less general relativity, are that the earth is 1) round and 2) orbiting the sun.  For the former, we start seeing evidence in the 5th and 6th centuries BC, with the idea becoming commonly accepted in the 4th century BC.  For the latter, the first person to present a working heliocentric model appears to be Aristachus of Samos, around 270 BC, though we don't know much about the details of that model.  One particularly interesting thing about Samos model is that it even starts to hint about an intuition regarding gravity, as one line of evidence he uses for the earth orbiting the Sun, rather than the other way around, is that when attempting to estimate the size of the sun and moon he determined that the sun had to be much, much larger than the earth, and surmised that the less massive thing would be more likely to orbit the more massive thing than vice versa.

So, let's say that everyone accepted that the earth was round in 500 BC, around the time that inkling first popped up.  Since we know that people around this time, like Anaxagoras, performed similar sun/moon measurements (though Anaxagoras thought the earth was flat), it's conceivable that someone, if using the same earth model that Aristarchus was using, would have come to the same conclusions.  If these conclusions were accepted right off, rather than being ignored for milennia as is the case in the real world, we could have, in theory, gotten a heliocentric model of the universe around 300-400 BC.

Ok, well now we need gravity.  So we have a heliocentric model of the universe, which means our circular orbits with epicycles are on borrowed time, and eliptical orbits will be figured out fairly quickly, and we have our intuition that less massive things orbit more massive things, so I actually think all the tools are there to figure this one out.  It took about 100 years to get from Copernicus proposing a heliocentric model to Kepler figuring out how to find the precise orbits of everything, and, from there, about 50 years for Newton to use that information to formulate the first theory of gravity, so, at first glance, we could guess that we could have had gravity by about 200-300 BC.  There is one more wrinkle there though.  Mathematics was far, far more advanced in Newton's time than it was in the 2nd century BC.  To get a theory of gravity out of the eliptical orbits of the planets, you need calculus.  Now Newton didn't have calculus yet when he did this.  He had to invent it, but he had the tools that he would need to do so.  Well, how early do we start seeing stuff that looks like calculus?  The first example of a calculus-like operation in the ancient world comes from Archimedes, who essentially discovered the integral before having the work lost for 2000 years, around 250ish BC.  So we're actually still on track to have a first draft theory of gravity by about 200 BC.  Whoo.  We're making good time!  Unfortunately, the road gets pretty rocky from here.

Aside from his sun/moon size calculations, the other primary line of evidence Aristachus used for his heliocentric model was the fact parallax couldn't be observed for the fixed stars, which implied that they must be really, really far away.  Of course, nowadays we can observe parallax in fixed stars because we have telescopes, but motions this small are not observable to the naked eye so Aristachus couldn't measure these distances, and so needed to settle for "really far away".  This is a problem because we've kind of hit a wall on what can be observed without advances in optics.  We can't see things like gravitational lensing or closer stars screwing with the position of more distant ones.  Lines of evidence like the procession of mercury not quite matching Newtonian calculations rely on such tiny differences that, likewise, we aren't seeing them without telescopes.  It's not completely beyond reason to imagine that, in our world where calculus actually took off when Archimedes discovered it because it explained the motion of the planets, the complex math that Einstein's thought experiments relied on, like the Lorentz Transformation, and physical measurements, like the speed of light, could have been independently discovered, but it's kind of hard to imagine someone even attempting similar thought experiments in a world where astronomical observations are limited to the naked eye and theories of motion, matter, and energy are much less developed than they were in 1905.  Even Einstein didn't actually know he was developing a theory of gravity when he first started toying with Special Relativity.  He was trying to explain the motion of high velocity objects and stumbled onto a connection between that and gravity while doing so.  I think getting from Gravity to Relativity is probably going to take a lot more development in a lot more areas than getting from a round earth to Gravity.

I think optics is a good litmus test to use here.  The first treatise on optics was written by Ptolemy in the 2nd century, so around our time for Newtonian gravity being discovered in our hypothetical instant adoption ancient Greece.  We don't really see lenses good enough to be used in telescopes until about the 1300s and don't actually see them being used that way until the 1600s, but, as with other discoveries on this list, we can imagine that if there was an application for telescopes when optics first started being described scientifically, there would be a motivation to push it in the direction of that application, so we can imagine that there would be more use for telescopes in our Instant Adoption world than in the real world.  So let's say that as soon as Ptolemy writes Optics, people are already hitting the ground running looking to improve on his theories to get something that can be turned skyward.  Well, making a perfect lens is kind of hard, and I think that reflective telescopes, which are really what we are going to need to measure these tiny differences in position that would show us that Newtonian relativity is incomplete, are still going to be a fairly long time coming, so, if I had to guess, completely discounting the Roman Conquest, the Fall of Rome, the Dark Ages, and other geopolitical considerations that would stymie progress toward such a theory, I'd say that, if everything went perfectly and nothing got lost, a working theory of relativity could have probably been developed somewhere between something like 200 and 800 AD.

Of course these numbers are kind of half pulled out of nowhere, based on little more than glancing at ideas left on the floor that could have made such advances happen, and, because of the technological progress that would need to accompany such a development in terms of things like mathematics and optics, you probably wouldn't be looking at a world quite like the 3rd to 9th centuries as we know it, but I think this is a fair approximation for worldbuilding purposes.

Answer (score -2):

It takes a second to shine a strong light on the nights moon and see it back, so having a giant, almost flat burning mirror, whos focus point you can compute - you can create a lightdot on the moon. https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-80981-1_2 and compute the distance.

Then you can switch it on and off - and measure the time. Giving you light speed for a roundtrip of light (back and forth).

c = (d * 2)/t

Then you can also use the other funny tests and try to flintstone these:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_general_relativity#Perihelion_precession_of_Mercury

Now comes the hard part, how much are you willing to admit advances into optics for experiments:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_special_relativity

Depending on how flintstoneable the experiments are, thats how close you can get to it..

So you want to measure light distortion by the gravity. You could do that via observation of the lightspot on the moon and using physical computing to compute expected deformation.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_computing

Comment: what does measuring the speed of light have to do with discovering relativity?

Comment: This with massive objects bending light https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_general_relativity#Deflection_of_light_by_the_Sun informs you about the "bended"ness of space and the "deformedness" of the observations?

Comment: Again, what has measuring the speed of light by shining a laser on a mirror on its surface has to do with it?

Comment: @L.Dutch The oddity at the root of SR is that light has the same speed in all reference frames.  That being said, the tests that lead to SR like Michelson-Moorley were measurements done on a scale of the Earth's orbit, not just to the moon.  It would be easier to argue that there is an Aether encompassing the Earth and moon.

Comment: @CortAmmon I am aware of all the shabang behind it. But Pica has failed to make it clear in their answer, where they suggest that 1 measure is enough to infer SR, while M&M took at least 2 measures to start cogitating about it.

Comment: @LDutch is right. I thought if you take the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Laser_Ranging_experiments#Principle and go from there, nibbling at the relativistic effects you could get there. I was wrong.

Comment: Could you [edit] to expand on your answer to clarify how it addresses the question.